# ONDELETE object event in javascript

Tags: javascript, object, destructor

I have a modal object that creates DOM elements when its created.
I would like to know if its possible to remove the nodes whenever user calls 'delete' on the object. Something like:

```
var modal = function (options) {
    var domHolder = null;

    function build() {
        domHolder = document.createElement("div");
        //construct a modal window inside the element...
    };

    this.ondelete = function() {
        domHolder.parentNode.removeChild(domHolder);
    }

    build();
};

//destruct the object and remove the nodes
var myModal = new modal();
delete myModal;
```

Comment: You can't, javascript don't have destructors.

Comment: Would a `WeakMap` help you?

Comment: Any examples @JanDvorak ??

Comment: Could you explain the purpose of the class you show. It's duties. My questions head for: "why exactly do you need a destructor in this context", any "maybe there's a workaround without destructor", but for this I'd have to understand the context. And this `delete` is kind of annoying me. It promises no good.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

delete doesn't trigger the onDeleteEvent , delete is an operator;

> The delete operator removes a property from an object.

You shoud call the ondelete method to remove the element from DOM.

```
var myModal = new modal();
myModal.ondelete() ;
```

JavaScript is automatically garbage collected; the object's memory will be reclaimed only if the Garbage Collectior decides to run and the object is eligible for that.

The delete operator has nothing to do with directly freeing memory (it only does indirectly via breaking references). See the [memory management](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Memory_Management) page for more details).

Comment: _The delete operator has nothing to do with directly freeing memory_ seriously o.O? Thanks for the references

Answer (score 1):

You could solve it like this:
*Call the delete function yourself instead of the delete operator*
*(I edited the code to do some cleanup.)*

```js
var modal = function (options) {
    var domHolder = null;

    function build() {
        domHolder = document.createElement("div");
        domHolder.innerHTML = "yes";
        document.getElementById("test").appendChild(domHolder);
    };

    this.delete = function() {
        domHolder.parentNode.removeChild(domHolder);
        delete domHolder;
        // delete ... other objectsthat can be released, ...
        // ... so that the instance can be garbage collected 
    }

    build();
};

//destruct the object and remove the nodes
var myModal = new modal();
document.getElementById("clear").addEventListener("click", function(){
     myModal.delete();
 })
```

```html
<div id="test">
</div>
<button id="clear">delete</button>
```

Comment: Good example. According to all answers/references we have to 'destruct' it manually.